# Prove norm inequality: $\|\mathrm x\|_2 \le \|\mathrm x\|_1$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

On $\Bbb R^n$, define for $\mathrm x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n)$ a norm

$$\|\mathrm x\|_1 := |x_1| + |x_2| + \cdots + |x_n|$$

By denoting the usual norm by $\|\mathrm x\|_2$, show that $\|\mathrm x\|_2 \le \|\mathrm x\|_1$ for all $\mathrm x$.

First of all, do I need to assume that all $\mathrm x$ for $\|\mathrm x\|_2$ is less than or equal to all $\mathrm x$ for $\|\mathrm x\|_1$? I'm a bit confused about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove the equivalent $(\forall \mathrm x\in \Bbb R^n)\left(\Vert \mathrm x\Vert_2 ^2\leq \Vert \mathrm x\Vert _1^2\right)$.

**Further hint:** Let $\mathrm x=(x_1,x_2, \ldots ,x_n)\in \Bbb R^n$. Note that $$\Vert \mathrm x\Vert_2^2=\left(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots +x_n^2}\right)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2.$$
Now square $\Vert \mathrm x\Vert_1$ and compare with what's above.

Comment: Still don't get it. You just squared norms.

Comment: I'm not sure of ||x||_2 here.

Comment: @therexists I added stuff to the answer. Does this help?

Comment: Then they are both the same. Aren't they? If I do the same for norm x_1, it will be the same.

Comment: Norm x_2 doesn't have to be less than norm x_1?

Comment: @therexists No, they aren't the same: $\Vert x_1 \Vert _1^2=(|x_1|+|x_2|+\ldots +|x_n|)^2=\ldots$, proceed.

Comment: Because of the parenthesis?

Comment: @therexists Yes. Try it with $n=2,3$ and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you so much. You totally helped me a lot! Thank you.

Comment: @therexists You're welcome.